# How to make the % (jump to matching bracket) key ignore commented-out code in Vim

Tags: vim

```
1  #include <stdio.h>
2  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
3    int i=10;
4  /* } */
5    return 0;
6  }
```

If the cursor is on line 2 under `{` and I press the <kbd>%</kbd> key, the cursor shows
the matching closing brace on line 4 (which is commented out) and not the matching
closing brace on line 6.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the [`matchit`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) plugin. It extends the `%` command in many ways, including skipping comments. Included with Vim but not enabled by default.

From it's docs:

> By default, words inside comments and strings are ignored, unless the cursor is inside a comment or string when you type "%".

I also just tried on your example and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm curious. I use matchit for filetypes like sh and html, but I'm hesitant to use it as a global plugin. Completely replacing the behavior of % doesn't sit right with me. I do like the idea of it skipping commented code. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't see a disadvantage in having it global. It doesn't remove any % functionality, just extends it. From `:h matchit`, if b:match_words is undefined you have standard %  with comment skipping. Most ftplugins set b:match_words, if you don't want it for a filetype try an autocmd to unset in vimrc